# need to use a patterns or bridge to use the api when mobile is online or local db when mobile is offline

Tags: c#, sqlite, api, xamarin.forms

hello i need to help i have a app in xamarin form and i use the **api** but i need to create a local database to save and use data in local db when mobile is offline so please can help me how to make that how to cretae a *pattern or bridge* to make automaticy when mobile is online to use the restapi and when is offline to use the local db please tell me how to make this because i need for this week or samples Code in C# to understand how can i create

Comment: check out the Breeze project: http://www.getbreezenow.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure - Take a look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data

Maybe it can help you either way.

Comment: i  not use the azure i use just c# mvc web api

Comment: Take a look at this anyway, maybe the connection with the .Net backend is simillar (asp.net web api is the backend)